# MongoDB / RoboMongo - Is it possible to integrate a clickable link or reference into a collection field?

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor, hyperlink, reference

I have no clue whether MongoDB provides such an option or not.

I have a local MongoDB in my meteor application connected to RoboMongo. So, I have my collections with many docs inside. Inside a doc, there are many fields with much plane text in it, like in

Collection1:

```
    {
     "_id": ObjectID("123456789"),
     "thing": firstThing,
     "type": text,
     "langEn"{
              "content": "This is so much senseless text like in (**X**), you don´t want to read ",
              "content2": "This is even more text like in (**Y**)...seriously?"
              "content3": "Ok...I´m out because of (**Z**)"
                 }
    }
```

So, X, Y and Z should be links like a href="#" or any reference, with that I can see the content of another collection on that site.

Because the user always decides by himself what he wants to see and therefore what is loaded onto the page from the collection, I can´t just write fix html-hashes on the site itself. It depends on which docs and fields are currently loaded on the site.

I tried to use html in MongoDB:

```
..."content": "This is so much senseless text like in <a href='#(**X**)'> Link to X </a>, ..."
```

But this fails...

Is there any way to make text of a MongoDB field a clickable link?

### Edit

The second code example is just a try (just leave it there, in case it is nonsense).

Comment: I have a couple of questions.  What do you mean "using RoboMongo as a UI"?  RoboMongo is a standalone app providing a front end interface to mongo.  How are you integrating this in a Meteor app?  Secondly, are you saying that `langEn.contentX` gets rendered in your web app and you are trying to provide a capability where the user can click it and it would take them to a different page with new data?

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do? can you show us the html that you have tried to use?

Comment: @jordanwillis  yeah, I see that my "wording" is quite incorrect. I editet the question to clarify these issues. You´re right, I use RoboMongo as a front end to mongo. I just connected the Robomongo with the local mongoDB of my meteor app. To your second question: Yes, exactly this is what I need (but not to a different page unconditionally, to a specific id within the page would also be an opportunity). Thanks for your additions.

Comment: @mutdmour      Yes, I see…again my declaration isn´t the best, sorry for that. As mentioned in my comment before, I just need to know whether there is way to make text in mongoDB which is rendered on the page to a link (equivalent to an html 'href'). I did not use an external html yet, I just tried to type html into mongoDB, but obviously this doesn´t work (actually I did not even believed that it would work, but I just wanted to give a try). Thanks for your effort!